# bizspark azure credit card details

Tags: azure, bizspark

Okay, I'm a BizSpark subscriber using my Azure credits and having a ball.
I've just tried to set up a web app on azure with a MySQL back end. WHen I tried to add MySQL to my subscription, it says I'm not allowed because it is a third-party product requiring that a credit card be registered on the Azure account as third-party products are not covered by the free Azure credit provided by Microsoft.

No Problem.

Except .... I Cannot find anywhere in my Azure portal where I can enter credit card details !
You normally have a link in your subscription settings (on a normal Azure account) but that link is missing on a BizSpark subscription.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. The most likely option to your current question is to open a billing support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure billing issue, not a programming question.

Comment: Go to https://account.windowsazure.com/Home/Index and after login, you should be able to update credit card information under billing section

Answer (score 3):

You don’t usually need to provide your credit card credentials when you own a BizSpark Subscription, however, as you stated yourself; MySQL is a third-party product requiring that a credit card to be registered. This is not the case for students using DreamSpark for instance, which restricts the students to a couple of resources. As a BizSpark however, you get those credits which you are free to use on resources except third party ones. In order to use these services, I imagine you put in your credit card on the BizSpark Subscription (not sure about this) or a “Pay-as-you-go”-subscription (definitely sure about this). In order to do so, I suggest you use the “old” portal called [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com). When you sign in to your account, follow these steps to put in your credit card: Click your account name in the top right corner => View my bill => Here you can see the different subscription details and usage info. Select one subscription => Change payment method.

If you don’t want to use MySQL, you could simply use MSSQL by simply following this guide:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/07/30/using-wordpress-on-windows-azure-with-sql-server-instead-of-mysql.aspx

Hope this solved your problem and answered your question.
Please put this topic as resolved.